# Where do I need to paste this "preload images" javascript code, and do I need to import anything?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know some javascript, but I'm not exactly sure if I need to import anything in HTML, and if this code should be in my index.html file, or if this should be some standalone .js file which gets called in HTML?

if in the index.html file, should it be in the body, the header, or where?

Here is the code:

```
function preloader() {
    if (document.images) {
        var img1 = new Image();
        var img2 = new Image();
        var img3 = new Image();

        img1.src = "http://domain.tld/path/to/image-001.gif";
        img2.src = "http://domain.tld/path/to/image-002.gif";
        img3.src = "http://domain.tld/path/to/image-003.gif";
    }
}
function addLoadEvent(func) {
    var oldonload = window.onload;
    if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
        window.onload = func;
    } else {
        window.onload = function() {
            if (oldonload) {
                oldonload();
            }
            func();
        }
    }
}
addLoadEvent(preloader);
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? That can be run from the page or from within a standalone file.

Comment: Could be inline in page HTML or loaded in with a script call.  Try it and see.  Nothing to "import".  Use browser dev tools to see impact on how page loads when pre-loading those images to see that it works.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice would be to write javascript functions in their own file and then include them in your html, but you can easily write the function within your html file (inside a `<script>` tag). The problem with the latter approach is when your code gets longer and more complicated, your script gets harder to understand and debug.

For your second question, you'll need to be more accurate on what you're trying to accomplish, because your script can either be placed in the header (usually libraries are placed there) or in the body of your html file (usually own-written scripts are placed there).

See this article (it's well explained) http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_whereto.asp